# Redirect to specific page when open domain by web.config

Tags: asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc

Now i want to make my website to redirect to specific page when any body try to open any page in it i used this code in web.config

```
  <system.webServer>
<rewrite>
  <rules>
    <rule name="HTTP to HTTPS redirect" stopProcessing="true"> <match url="(.*)" />
       <conditions>
          <add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="^.+$" ignoreCase="true" />
       </conditions>
       <action type="Redirect"  url="https://mydomain/image.jpg" />
    </rule> 
 </rules>
```

but when i tried to open the website i didn't redirect to the page that i want but i got message in browser "redirect loop" , so any body know the reason and how to solve this issue and thanks in advance

Comment: your Server Admin team can setup complete website redirection from the site hosted on one server to another website hosted on another server; you need not code for this; contact your team

Comment: i didn't mean what you understand i mean when i type my domain i need to redirect to page under this domain that's it

Comment: i see you are redirecting to jpg which doesn't make sense to me!! what is your objective?

Comment: when you say <match url="(.*)" /> it itself includes your jpg; so you end up going in an infinite redirect loop; you need to exclude the page you want to land on

Comment: add another input with negate attribute; it should serve your purpose

Comment: yes i got that but i didn't find way to exclude this image !

Comment: try something like this <add input="{REQUEST_URI}" negate="true" pattern="image.jpg" ignoreCase="true" />

Comment: or alternatively change match string to (*.aspx) instead of (.*)

Comment: thanks for your reply but i use it and still get redirect loop